# Antlr 3 keywords and identifiers colliding

Tags: tokenize, antlr3, context-free-grammar

Surprise, I am building an SQL like language parser for a project.

I had it mostly working, but when I started testing it against real requests it would be handling, I realized it was behaving differently on the inside than I thought.

The main issue in the following grammar is that I define a lexer rule **PCT_WITHIN** for the language keyword '**pct_within**'. This works fine, but if I try to match a field like '**attributes.pct_vac**', I get the field having text of '**attributes.ac**' and a pretty ANTLR error of:

```
line 1:15 mismatched character u'v' expecting 'c'
```

GRAMMAR

```
grammar Select;

options {
  language=Python;
}

eval returns [value]
    : field EOF 
    ;

field returns [value]
    : fieldsegments {print $field.text}
    ;

fieldsegments
    : fieldsegment (DOT (fieldsegment))*
    ;

fieldsegment
    : ICHAR+ (USCORE ICHAR+)*
    ;

WS                      : ('\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n')+ {self.skip();};

ICHAR                   : ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z');

PCT_CONTAINS            : 'pct_contains';

USCORE                  : '_';
DOT                     : '.';
```

I have been reading everything I can find on the topic. How the Lexer consumes stuff as it finds it even if it is wrong. How you can use semantic predication to remove ambiguity/how to use lookahead. But everything I read hasn't helped me fix this issue.

Honestly I don't see how it even CAN be an issue. I must be missing something super obvious because other grammars I see have Lexer rules like **EXISTS** but that doesn't cause the parser to take a string like '**existsOrNot**' and spit out and **IDENTIFIER** with the text of '**rNot**'.

What am I missing or doing completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your fieldsegment parser rule into a lexer rule. As it stands now it will accept  input like

```
"abc      
_     abc"
```

which is probably not what you want. The keyword "pct_contains" won't be matched by this rule since it is defined separately. If you want to accept the keyword in certain sequences as regular identifier you will have to include it in the accepted identifier rule.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That might have fixed it (adding the rest of the grammar back slowly and testing). Even if this works, I am still confused. Why with my grammar didn't the lexer look at the pct_vac and say 'This isn't a pct_within token, I will just emit several ICHAR tokens' and instead said 'of crap *shoots self*'?

Comment: You have no lexer rule that matches an identifier including an underscore. So the lexer only has one rule to match "pct_vac" (namley PCT_CONTAINS). This fails, so you get the error. By making fieldsegment a lexer rule you fix this as now there is a rule that matches "pct_vac" since it is not defined as an own rule.

Comment: This exposes some real lack of knowledge on my part. I assumed it would not match pct_contains and instead output individual ICHAR tokens, a USCORE token, and then more ICHAR tokens...