# ANTLR: "for" keyword used for loops conflicts with "for" used in messages

Tags: sequence, antlr4, grammar, rules

I have the following grammar:

```
myg                : line+ EOF ;

line                : ( for_loop | command params ) NEWLINE;

for_loop : FOR WORD INT DO NEWLINE stmt_body;

stmt_body: line+ END;

params              : ( param | WHITESPACE)*;

param                : WORD | INT;

command             : WORD;


fragment LOWERCASE  : [a-z] ;
fragment UPPERCASE  : [A-Z] ;
fragment DIGIT : [0-9] ;

WORD                : (LOWERCASE | UPPERCASE | DIGIT | [_."'/\\-])+ (DIGIT)* ;
INT : DIGIT+ ;
WHITESPACE          : (' ' | '\t')+ -> skip;
NEWLINE             : ('\r'? '\n' | '\r')+ -> skip;
FOR: 'for';
DO: 'do';
END: 'end';
```

My problem is that the 2 following are valid in this language:

```
message please wait for 90 seconds
```

This would be a valid command printing a message with the word "for".

```
for n 2 do
```

This would be the beginning of a `for` loop.

The problem is that with the current lexer it doesn't match the for loop since 'for' is matched by the WORD rule as it appears first.

I could solve that by putting the FOR rule before the WORD rule but then 'for' in message would be matched by the FOR rule

Comment: Can you restrict `command` that it cannot be one of the other keywords? This means that when the token `for` is at the beginning, it is a `for_loop`, otherwise, it is a `command`.

Comment: This would be possible. How would that help though since during the Lex'ing the 'for' would still be tokenized as WORD(since it appears first) no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the typical keywords versus identifier problem and I thought there were quite a number of questions regarding that here on Stackoverflow. But to my surprise I can only find an [old answer of mine for ANTLR3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16866612/antlr-3-keywords-and-identifiers-colliding).

Even though the principle mentioned there remains the same, you no longer can change the returned token type in a parser rule, with ANTLR4.

There are 2 steps required to make your scenario work.

1. Define the keywords before the `WORD` rule. This way they get own token types you need for grammar parts which require specific keywords.
2. Add keywords selectively to rules, which parse names, where you want to allow those keywords too.

For the second step modify your rules:

```
param: WORD | INT | commandKeyword;
command: WORD | commandKeyword;
commandKeyword: FOR | DO | END; // Keywords allowed as names in commands.
```

Comment: Thx. So this means that 'for' in a message will be produced as a FOR token, not a word, just that in terms of parsing will take place correctly in the AST. Is this the mechanism?

Comment: Yes exactly. So when you walk your parse tree you should be aware that you can get either `WORD`, INT or one of the keywords as content. With ANTLR3 I was able to change the token type of such recognized keywords to `ID` to make this simpler. This is no longer possible with ANTLR4.